# Error when fetching json data with ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I have some json data that coming from my php code here it is

```json
{"Inboxunreadmessage":4,
 "aaData":[{
     "Inboxsubject":"Email SMTP Test",
     "Inboxfrom":"Deepak Saini <*****@*****.co.in>"},
  {"Inboxsubject":"Testing01",
     "Inboxfrom":"Deepak Saini <**********@gmail.com>"}
]}
```

I'm fatching it like this

```javascript
$(window).load(function(){
    $.ajax({
        dataType: "json",
        type: "POST",
        url: "/mail/mail-action",
        data: {
            _act: "load"
        }
    }).done(function(data) {
        if(data.message){
            showMessage(data);
        }
     //This is working 
        $('.Inboxunreadmessage').html(data.Inboxunreadmessage);
     //This is Not working ----------------------
        $('.Inboxsubject').html('<li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-users text-aqua"></i> '+data.Inboxsubject+'</a></li>');
    }).error(function(jqxhr, exception){
        ajaxErrorHandler(jqxhr, exception);
    });
});
```

I'm getting error in

```
$('.Inboxsubject').html('<li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-users text-aqua"></i> '+data.Inboxsubject+'</a></li>');
```

Comment: Philipp my client side working properly its getting data as you see

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are accessing the data with a wrong JSON path.

`data.Inboxsubject` should be changed to `data.aaData[0].Inboxsubject`. This will print the first Inboxsubject of the `data.aaData` array.

Now since `data.aaData` is an array, you could loop over it to print out all Inboxsubjects.

```
var blockhtml="";
for(var i=0;i<data.aaData.length;i++)
{
    blockhtml= blockhtml+'<li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-users text-aqua"></i> '+data.aaData[i]["Inboxsubject"]+'</a></li>'
}

$('.Inboxsubject').html(blockhtml);
```

Comment: Its showing error here for(var i=0;i<data.aaData.length){ and error is Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token )

Comment: Opps Done "i++"

Answer (score 1):

The data you are receiving has an array with further data in it...

```
{
    "Inboxunreadmessage":4,
    "aaData":[{
        "Inboxsubject":"Email SMTP Test",
        "Inboxfrom":"Deepak Saini <*****@*****.co.in>"
    }, {
        "Inboxsubject":"Testing01",
        "Inboxfrom":"Deepak Saini <**********@gmail.com>"
    }]
}
```

So to get the first subject you would use...

```
data.aaData[0].Inboxsubject
```

to get the next one you would use...

```
data.aaData[1].Inboxsubject
```

To parse all the `aaData` objects, you could use this...

```
data.aaData.forEach(function(aa) {
    // here you have aa.Inboxsubject and aa.Inboxfrom
});
```